# Map a Normalized Postgres View to Entity | SringBoot

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have multiple tables with one to many relationships. for example:

```
Document
- id
- filename
- status

Field ( relation b/w document & field is 1 to many )
- id
- type
- fk_document_id -> Document::id

FieldValue ( relation b/w field & field_value is 1 to many )
- id
- value
- fk_field_id -> Field::id

Coordinates ( relation b/w field_value & coordinate is 1 to many )
- id
- start_x
- start_y
- end_x
- end_y
- fk_field_value_id -> FieldValue::id
```

as i can't access these tables directly from my project so i create a view

```
CREATE VIEW AS
 SELECT * FROM document doc
   LEFT JOIN field ON doc.id=field.document_id
   LEFT JOIN field_value ON field.id=field_value.field_id
   LEFT JOIN coordinate ON field_value.id=coordinate.id;
```

The result set of view for one document would look something like:

```
document_id | filename  | field_id  | type   | field_value_id   | value  | coordinate_id | start_x   | start_y ...
id_1        | test.pdf  | f_id_1    | single | f_v_id_1         | test1  | c_id_1        | 0         | 1
id_1        | test.pdf  | f_id_1    | single | f_v_id_1         | test1  | c_id_2        | 1         | 3
id_1        | test.pdf  | f_id_1    | single | f_v_id_2         | test2  | c_id_3        | 2         | 4
id_1        | test.pdf  | f_id_1    | single | f_v_id_2         | test2  | c_id_4        | 0         | 5
```

i have entities defined in Java which looks like following:

```
class Document {
    String id;
    String filename;
    List<Field> fields;
}

class Field {
    String id;
    Sring type;
    List<FieldValue> values;
}

class FieldValue {
    String id;
    String value;
    List<Cordinate> coordinates;
}

class Coordinate {
    String id;
    int start_x;
    int start_y;
    int end_x;
    int end_y;
}
```

**So how do i map the result from view to the document entity?**

*Note: i can't create multiple views as in actual scenario i have lots of tables.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible, you can't map one-to-many associations which were flattened in a view as entity. Hibernate has no way to manage the rows properly this way. You don't need the view though. Hibernate is perfectly capable of creating a query like the one you are using for the view on demand.

Comment: Hi Chistian, actually the use case is such that i can't directly access the tables, i can only access views or can even stored procedures would work.

Comment: That's fine but how about you create a view per table then and map every view to it's own entity? If that doesn't work for you, you will have to map the view to a flat entity. You can use Blaze-Persistence though if you want to create richer projections with collections on top of this model.